# Why is Windows 2003 Enterprise not using all memory?

Tags: windows-server-2003, memory

How do I force Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition 64 Bit to use the available Memory in the system?

It is a Windows 2003 Enterprise Edition 64 Bit running on an HP DL380 Server with 32GB of RAM. Terminal Services are running out of the box serving applications such as Outlook and a couple of custom apps. Performance of the server seems to be slow and looking at the reports it doesn't seem to use more than 4 Gig of RAM. The remaining memory seems to be sitting there in the server without getting any use.

Comment: We need some details about what system you are concerned about - make\model and the amount and type of memory installed that you aren't seeing. as lynnroth answered if the memory is correctly installed and supported by the hardware W2K3 64 bit it should be automatically used.

Comment: Also assuming that Windows is at least aware of the total amount of RAM installed, we would need to know what application or service you are expecting to use the memory.  Also, please confirm that an amd64 version of said product exists, and that someone hasn't installed the x86 version by mistake.

Comment: Explain "use memory". Windows will always only use the memory it needs.

Answer (score 3):

It should automatically use the memory that is available.

Possibly a BIOS setting that would cause it to reduce the amount of memory available.

Could you describe the scenario you are experiencing?